# Instagram OAuthAccessTokenException Error

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram gallery just to display **10** most recent images on my site page but in every alternate day it throws below error

> {"error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}

And I need to generate a new access_token to resolve this issue.

Is there any way to get this work permanently, So I do not need to generate new access_token on each alternate day

Below is my code to display this gallery on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 10;
      var clientID = 'xxxxxxxx';
      var accessToken = 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx';

      var jsonpURL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?client_id=" + clientID + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "&callback=listImages&count=" + count;

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = jsonpURL;
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      head.appendChild(script);

function listImages(response) {
  var i, item, len, images;
  images = '';
  if (response.data.length > 0) {
    var entries = response.data;
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('instagram-wrapper');
    for (i = 0, len = entries.length; i < len; i++) {
      item = entries[i];
      if(item.type == 'video'){
        images += '<div class="grid-item"><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank" class="fancybox-instagram"><video muted src="' + item.videos.low_bandwidth.url + '" onmouseenter="this.play()" onmouseleave="this.pause()"></video></a></div>';
      }else {
        images += '<div class="grid-item"><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank" class="fancybox-instagram"><img src="' + item.images.standard_resolution.url + '"></a></div>';
      }
      if( i==2 ){
        var smallProfileImage = item.user.profile_picture;
        var userProfileImg = smallProfileImage.replace("s150x150/","");
        images += '<div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><a href="http://urlgeni.us/instagram/BU1l" target="_blank"><img src="{{ 'profile.jpg' |  asset_url }}"></a></div>';
      }

    }
    if( wrapper != null ){

        wrapper.innerHTML = images;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I am using my app in sandbox mode and I have tried to submit my app for review but it shows below information

Screenshot of when I tried to submit my app fro review:

[image]

> I am using this code just to fetch 10 most recent images from my own
>   Instagram account to display it on my website.